# How to jump around a sound in pygame?

Tags: audio, pygame, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a media player with Pygame because it comes native on raspbian. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to jump around in a song. The API says there is a way to get the current location in the song and the length of the song, but there is no documented way to jump to an arbitrary position. I need to do this in order to scrub in a media player. Or if someone knows of another python library that ports easily to the Raspberry Pi that would be helpful as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could only manage it for music, not Sound:

```py
import pygame, time

pygame.mixer.init()
m = pygame.mixer.music

filename = r"C:\Python32\Lib\site-packages\pygame\examples\data\house_lo.ogg"

m.load(filename)

print("Playing " + filename)
m.play(0, 0)
time.sleep(1)

print("Stopping at {}".format(m.get_pos() / 1000.0))
m.stop()
#time.sleep(0.5)

print("Playing after seek")
m.play(0, 3)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: That will work! I didn't see the arguments to play for music. Thank you.